# From a point P($\alpha$ ,$\beta$), two tangents PQ and PR are drawn to circle x$^2$+y$^2$=a$^2$=0.

Tags: coordinate-systems

From a point P($\alpha$ ,$\beta$), two tangents PQ and PR are drawn to circle

**x$^2$+y$^2$=a$^2$**
Lets call this T

Find the equation of circumcircle of of triangle PQR.
What I did was As follows
Let the equation of circle be

**x$^2$+y$^2$+2gx+2fy+c=0.**
Lets call this S

equation of line QR will be the radical axis of those two circles. Which is

**x$\alpha$+y$\beta$-a$^2$=0**

So we can conclude T-S=**x$\alpha$+y$\beta$-a$^2$=0**
Equation of radical axis

Which produces multiple solutions(equation of radical axis could be multiplied to any constant).

Like:

**x$^2$+y$^2$-$\alpha$x-$\beta$y=0.**

**x$^2$+y$^2$+$\alpha$x+$\beta$y-a$^2$=0**

This is where i am stuck.

Comment: typo has been corrected

Comment: In this particular problem, there's a trick that since $OQ \perp PQ$ and $OR \perp PR$ (where $O = (0, 0)$ is the center of the original circle), in fact $Q$ and $R$ must both be on the circle with diameter $OP$.  So, the circumcircle of $PQR$ must be that circle with diameter $OP$, i.e. $x^2 + y^2 - \alpha x - \beta y = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$T = x^2+y^2 -a^2, \>\>\>\>\>S=\alpha x +\beta y -a^2$$

Then, the equation of circumcircle of of triangle PQR is $T-S=0$, i.e.

$$ x^2+y^2 -\alpha x -\beta y=0$$

where there is no ambiguity.

Comment: you can multiply any constant to S making multiple circles. ie S could be a$^2$-$\alpha$x-$\beta$y. Through this we can make multiple equation of circles each different